# can you load an app developed on a mac "in the cloud" onto your ios device?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, xcode

I'm curious if it would still be possible to develop for the iPhone with a non Mac laptop. Assume I buy some sort of "Mac in the cloud" solution (they exist), can I download apps I'm developing onto my iOS devices from Xcode on this "remote Mac" via my iCloud/developer account or do I need physical access to a Mac (usb cable) to do that?

This [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/92709/92724) seems to indicate that it's not possible to load apps onto local devices from a remote Mac, but he's not sure.

EDIT: Actually, it seems to be possible to debug too, see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if you have a paid developer account you can create signed IPAs which can be installed on the device remotely, or you can use TestFlight. If you don't have a paid developer account but your device is jailbroken you can install unsigned IPAs. Note that this doesn't include debugging which can't be done remotely.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it seems like this software lets you share a usb connection with an ios device between a local mac or non-mac pc and a mac you keep at home or a "mac in the cloud". Add a remote login to this combination and it seems like you can develop for ios without having a physical mac with you.

"With USB Network Gate you can connect your iPhone via USB to your Windows/Mac workstation and share this USB connection with other computers."

Other computer like some mac in the cloud.

http://www.net-usb.com/iphone-app-development/